# Quarkus and CDI Extensions

Tags: migration, cdi, quarkus, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to migrate an project build upon **Thorntail + Jakarta EE** to Quarkus.

In my first test I found a problem with custom CDI accesss:

```
11:10:27,381 INFO  [io.qua.dep.QuarkusAugmentor] Beginning quarkus augmentation
11:10:27,559 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.0.0.Beta4
11:10:27,709 ERROR [io.qua.dev.DevModeMain] Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ConfigurationSetup#initializeConfiguration threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate CDIProvider
        at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:132)
        at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.doStart(DevModeMain.java:166)
        at io.quarkus.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:88)
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ConfigurationSetup#initializeConfiguration threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate CDIProvider
        at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:108)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:121)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:104)
        at io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeRunner.run(RuntimeRunner.java:98)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate CDIProvider
        at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.findAllProviders(CDI.java:121)
        at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.getCDIProvider(CDI.java:82)
        at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current(CDI.java:64)
```

How can I handle this problem? There is any solution for this without making big changes on my project?

Comment: Can you give more information, what's the extention that you use? Maybe the pom.xml ?
I don't understant what you means by custom CDI access ...

Comment: Sorry, I cannot provide this kind of information. But you can see in the log that my extension is calling `CDI.current()` programmatically.

Comment: So first of all Quarkus does not support CDI portable extensions which are inherently runtime constructs and would limit the build-time optimizations it performs. Looking at the stack trace it seems that there's something which attempts to access `CDI.current()` before the container is started, during build. What CDI portable extensions are you actually using?

Comment: @MartinKouba, this is a bad news. But a good approach for a refactor before migrating to Quarkus. So what is the approach to replace it?

Comment: Well, it depends on which CDI extensions you're using. But in general, a Quarkus extension would be needed to simulate the logic from the CDI extension using the build-time extension points: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#build-time-extension-points